# NULL при попытке загрузить локальный JSON-файл

Tags: php

Привет. Многочисленные темы, созданные на StackOverflow говорят, что загрузить локальный `.json`-файл и превратить его в многомерный массив нужно так:

```
$cities = json_decode(file_get_contents("cities.json"), true);
```

Но у меня *что-то пошло не так*. Эта строчка кода выдаёт мне NULL. При этом, если сделать `print_r(file_get_contents("cities.json"));`, то выведется нужный мне json-файл в виде строки. Я что-то делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в кодировке. JSON-файлы должны быть закодированы в **UTF-8 без BOM**.

Answer (score -1):

В 7.2 уже json_decode уже сам начнет сообщать об ошибках, а пока надо использовать json_last_error_msg(), получать сообщение об ошибке, и только потом исправлять, конкретную ошибку

Comment: 7.2 пока что в бете.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin И ЧТО?

Comment: Предлагаете мне, значит, в продакшен пихнуть НЕстабильную версию PHP? ммммм

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin что я предлагаю, написано в моем ответе. Рекомендую купить очки